# Superscript "Registered mark" in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview, superscript

I need to show a registered trademark symbol in a superscript (exponent position) in respect to the name of the label. need to show it in a uipickerView and a label. I havent found the option of how to show the unicode \u00AE in the exponent position,

1) Should I use 2 labels in different positions in the uipickerView?
2) Or, Show an image in the picker view with the intended name?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an image in the picker view to show the superscript as needed,

inspired by the catalog app from apple,

if you are a noob like me and would like to check the project, please go to

[project in Github](https://github.com/mako34/PickeL)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

@"Sometext \u00AE other text".

Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

The unicode symbol is very slightly superscripted but I guess this isn't enough for you. You can't mix font sizes and styles within a label so there isn't an easy answer. Two labels probably won't work because you will be having to adjust the position of the R sign.

The simplest answer is probably to subclass UILabel and, in the drawRect method, call the super implementation and then manually draw the R string where you want it. You can get the size of the existing text using the NSString drawing methods so you'll know where to put the symbol.